IAM user policy not filtering lambdas correctly
I added the following inline policy to IAM user. The Role should only see lambdas tagged with environment:development.  but this gives error.  i am following this doc. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/attribute-based-access-control.html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:GetAccountSettings",
                "lambda:ListFunctions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/environment": "development"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}



User: arn:aws:sts::11111111:assumed-role/theRole/user1 is not
authorized to perform: lambda:GetAccountSettings on resource: *
because no identity-based policy allows the lambda:GetAccountSettings
action

if i remove the entire condition field the user can list all lambdas fine. with some warning at the top. what is the problem with the Condition?
Tags failed to load. The filter doesn't include tags.


You should break your policy up into two statements. Your tag condition is only relevant to listing the functions and not for getting your account settings. lambda:GetAccountSettings should be "*" without any conditions. Something like:
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
       "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "lambda:GetAccountSettings"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "lambda:ListFunctions"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:ResourceTag/environment": "development"
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}


And regarding your tags failing to load, you will need to also allow tags, which i think is "Lambda:ListTags"
